# Similarity orbit of compact operators

Tags: reference-request, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am considering a problem connecting the spectra of compact operators to larger class of operators.

Since spectra are invariant under similarity, I wonder whether there is a good reference on similarity orbit of compact operators.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by orbit of compact operator?